# Synchronous update of form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, synchronous

This is basically a simple question, but I haven't found a good answer here or with Google.

We have a Ruby on Rails app with a form that needs to update a section when the user changes the selected option in a pulldown menu.  The complication is that this update will be from the database - it can't realistically store and hide all the possible data when it loads.  The obvious solution is an Ajax call, but the problem is that Ajax is asynchronous, and our update is inherently synchronous.  We need to ensure that the user gets the updated info before submitting or doing any other work on the form.

I know one can (but shouldn't) specify that an Ajax call be synchronous, but is there a better approach to this?  I hate to do a separate post and reload every time the user selects a different option in one field, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for a situation like this.

Update:  I tried switching to using an XMLHttpRequest object in JavaScript, and it may work (I'm figthing with Rails routing issues right now), but it gives me a warning that the synchronous option for this object is deprecated.  Is there really no accepted way to get synchronous communication between a web page and server?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to send the post request every time? I use POST requests on keyups for auto-complete searching all the time (Google does as well) and I've never had a problem.

Comment: I thought repeatedly posting from a page and reloading it every time some detail of it changed was frowned upon (and very slow).

Comment: Go to google.com, Firebug the page. go to the console view and check 'Persist'. You'll see that Google makes a Get request every time you add a letter to the search form. Like I said, I do it all the time. Never had a problem. If you're reloading the whole page it will get slow, but if you just write some Javascript to change the relevant parts of the page it should be really fast.

Comment: Right - I can make a post from within the JavaScript, and use the results, can't I?  I've only been posting from submit buttons, and forgot it's more flexible than that.

Comment: Yeah, you can fire a post request on the form element change and use the callback to update the page content.

Comment: Just to clarify:
1)  This will enforce synchronicity, right?  So there is no way for the user to move on to the next field before we've updated what we need to?
2)  I need to use post because there's quite a bit of data coming back, but would this work with get, as well?

Comment: Yeah, if you need real-time synchronicity you might consider using a library like react.js. If you're only updating a few fields on a single object you can get away with using callbacks, but it can get complicated if you have several models/associations.